# Do C++ Concepts allow for my class at declaration/definition to specify it satisfies certain concept?

Tags: c++, c++-concepts, c++20

Currently best way I can think of is to use static_assert, but I would prefer nicer way.

```
#include <set>
#include <forward_list>

using namespace std;

template<typename C>
concept bool SizedContainer = requires (C c){
    c.begin();
    c.end();
    {c.size()} -> size_t;
};

static_assert(SizedContainer<std::set<int>>);
static_assert(!SizedContainer<std::forward_list<int>>);
static_assert(!SizedContainer<float>);

class MyContainer{
public:
    void begin(){};
    void end(){};
    size_t size(){return 42;}; 
};

static_assert(SizedContainer<MyContainer>);



int main()
{
}
```

Comment: First I got hyped and wanted to use the CRTP, but then I remembered `MyContainer` would be incomplete, and so the concept check would likely fail. So I don't see a better way.

Comment: @StoryTeller I tried FWD declaration and static assert before class MyContainer, but then it just silently fails... Could be same underlying problem.

Comment: Why is `static_assert` not an appropriate way to test this? It seems very clear to me what needs to be checked. And the entirety of a class's conceptual interface is not bound by its definition, so there's no reason to expect such checks to be part of the definition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently no, the keyword you would be looking for to do that would be `requires` 
From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints)

> The keyword `requires` is used in two ways: 1) To introduce a
>   requires-clause, which specifies constraints on template arguments or
>   on a function declaration.

Since you are not dealing with a function declaration, this is irrelevant. 
The second case is

> To begin a requires-expression, which is a prvalue expression of type
>   bool that describes the constraints on some template arguments. Such
>   expression is true if the corresponding concept is satisfied, and
>   false otherwise:

Which is not relevent here again because you are not trying to validate a constraint on some template arguments